# How do I anchor the axis title to the x-axis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

After reversing the number order on the y-axis, and setting the x-axis to cross at 1 instead of at 0, the x-axis title is no longer next to the axis:

[image]

Is there any way to anchor the axis title to the axis, ideally in the white area below it? Searching the properties for axis-title, I don't find anything about where it is positioned.

Comment: One workaround, till you find the solution, is to create a textbox, with no fill and no line. Here you can input the axis title and place it whereever you like.

Comment: Can't you just drag it to where you want it, or is that not what you mean by "anchor"?

Comment: @Firee That is my current workaround. However, I would very much like it to automatically move with the axis, in case of future changes to the graph.

Comment: @eirikdaude Could you upload the excel file, so that we can have a better look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible without using VBA, but with VBA it can be automated to trigger on any chart changes.  This code assumes the chart is an *embedded chart* (embedded in a worksheet), as opposed to a *chart sheet*.

1. Select the `Developer` tab ([instructions if it is not shown](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)).
2. Select `Editor`.
3. In the Project window right-click anywhere and select `Insert`, `Module`.
4. With the new Module window selected press <kbd>F6</kbd> (or click `View` then `Properties Window`).
5. Change the Name to `ChartEventModule`, and close the Properties window.
6. Paste the following code into the `ChartEventModule` window:

**ChartEventModule code:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim chartEventClassModule As New chartEventClassModule
Private Const chartSheet = "Sheet1"
Private Const chartNumber = 1

Sub RecalculateXAxisTitlePosition()
    Dim chart As chart, plot As PlotArea, axis As axis, title As AxisTitle, titleXPos As Double, titleYPos As Double

    Set chart = Worksheets(chartSheet).ChartObjects(chartNumber).chart
    Set plot = chart.PlotArea
    Set axis = chart.Axes(xlCategory) ' xlCategory is X axis, xlValue is Y axis

    ' If the X axis doesn't have a title, exit out
    If Not axis.HasTitle Then Exit Sub

    Set title = axis.AxisTitle

    ' Not necessary to set font size and text each time
    title.Text = "Verknadsgrad"
    title.Font.Size = 12

    ' .Position can be xlChartElementPositionAutomatic (-4105) or xlChartElementPositionCustom (-4114)
    title.Position = xlChartElementPositionCustom

    ' Without a title the plotarea top is 9
    ' With a title font size 12 the title height is 17.4, and the plotarea top is 26.4
    plot.Top = 9

    ' The PlotArea includes the axes.  The Y axis throws off our centering if we center based on the PlotArea.
    titleXPos = axis.Left + (axis.Width / 2) - (title.Width / 2)
    titleYPos = plot.Top + plot.Height

    title.Left = titleXPos
    title.Top = titleYPos

    ' OPTIONAL CODE
    ' This code sets the background fill to DiagonalDown, which ensures it goes exactly from corner to corner
    With plot.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .TwoColorGradient Style:=msoGradientDiagonalDown, variant:=1
        ' Green color
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 0)
        ' Red color
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ' Percentage to be fully red (<=15%)
        .GradientStops(1).Position = 0.15
        ' Percentage to be fully green (>=85%)
        .GradientStops(2).Position = 0.85
        ' Middle color (yellow), center point (50%), Transparency (0%), Point to insert into list of gradients (1)
        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(255, 255, 0), 0.5, 0, 1
    End With
End Sub

Sub Initialise()
    Set chartEventClassModule.myChart = Worksheets(chartSheet).ChartObjects(chartNumber).chart
End Sub
```

*I didn't like that when I set up the gradient I had to set a static angle, so I set it in code.  It is set to `DiagonalDown` which automatically calculates the angle depending on the aspect ratio of the chart.*

7. Make sure to set the 2 constants `chartSheet` and `chartNumber` appropriately at the top of the code.
8. Back in the Project window, right-click and create a `Class Module`.
9. Using the same Properties Window (<kbd>F6</kbd>), set the name to `ChartEventClassModule`.
10. Paste the following code into the `ChartEventClassModule` window:

**ChartEventClassModule code:**

```
Option Explicit

' https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/using-events-with-embedded-charts
Public WithEvents myChart As chart

Private Sub myChart_Calculate()
    Call ChartEventModule.RecalculateXAxisTitlePosition
End Sub

Private Sub myChart_Resize()
    Call ChartEventModule.RecalculateXAxisTitlePosition
End Sub

Private Sub myChart_SeriesChange(ByVal SeriesIndex As Long, ByVal PointIndex As Long)
    Call ChartEventModule.RecalculateXAxisTitlePosition
End Sub
```

*This code detects changes to the chart and re-runs the function to set the axis title.  Unfortunately we are [limited in the Chart events available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886305/excel-chart-change-event)*.

11. In the Project window double-click `ThisWorkbook`, and paste the following code:

**ThisWorkbook code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ChartEventModule.Initialise
End Sub
```

12. Save the workbook as a *macro-enabled* workbook (.xlsm).  Close and re-open the workbook.

**Presto!**  Now on any changes to the chart data, series, or size will trigger an event that causes it to recalculate the axis title position:[image: Final excel chart image]